# Change the position of html code of jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I use **jquery-ui-1.11.4** dialog to show a form, but the html of popup is placed after all other elements in `<body>` by default, so this code is not in the `<form>` element used by the parent view. That is the reason why the input values do not post to the controller in MVC3. I want to move the html code into `<form>` element. How can I do this?

Comment: Show your source code, it is not very clear what you want with out seeing what you have done!

Comment: Specifically, how are you creating your jQuery UI dialog? If you are using a specific element when creating it, you can pick the `<form>` element, then your submission will work as needed...

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be to render a View that you load into your popup.

E.g.

```
 $(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        title: 'the title',
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            //Load a partial view
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("PartialViewForm")");
        }
    });
 });
```

So the partial view would need to render your form.